# ros-hydro-pocketsphinx permission problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,

current ros-hydro-pocketsphinx package cannot be launched or executed,
because of incorrect permissions of the python node scripts.
Setting the execute permission for python nodes is a workaround.

Who can fix it for the future ?

Cheers
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81371/ros-hydro-pocketsphinx-permission-problem/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created a ticket for this here: https://github.com/mikeferguson/pocketsphinx/issues/5

I should be able to get a patch + new release out over the weekend.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-09-20**:
Fixed in 0.2.1.